# initializing for autogenerating rspec tests

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm new to Rspec and trying to have Rspec create new tests for something variable. Here's what I've tried:

```
require 'rspec'

describe 'a test' do

    @array = []
    before(:all) do
        @array = [1,3,4,6,9,2]
    end

    @array.each do |i|
        it { i.should > 3 }
    end

    it { @array.should have(4).items }
end
```

Unfortunately, the array doesn't seem to get filled before the `.each` block runs. Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

The `before` block doesn't get executed until just before `RSpec` starts to execute the `it` blocks.  But you're iterating through `@array` in the outer body of `describe`, so @array is still `nil` at that point. Within the last `it` block, @array *has* been initialized.

You can put pretty much any code you want within an `it` block. For example, you could write:

```
it "should have elements > 3" do
  @array.each do |i|
    i.should > 3
  end
end
```

Or, if you want separate `it` calls, you can just populate `@array` in the describe block itself, as in:

```
describe 'a test' do

    @array = [1,3,4,6,9,2]

    @array.each do |i|
        it { i.should > 3 }
    end

    it { @array.should have(4).items }
end
```

although you might want to rework it in this case so that you pass a string argument to `it` indicating which element of the array (i.e. what index) you're operating on.

As for dynamically generating `it` statements based on data defined in the `let`/`before` hierarchy, I don't think that's possible, because you only have access to that data within an `it` block and `it` is not part of the acceptable DSL within an `it` block.

Comment: I understand but then how can I make it work from within an it block then? Because rspec won't allow for nested `it`

Comment: What are you trying to test? Tests should only contain assertions that you expect to be true with properly functioning production code. You can certainly place an iteration inside of an `it` block. I'll update my answer to indicate that.

Comment: that's certainly a viable way to go, but it is still only one test. what i'd like is to have rspec *generate* these tests for me. for instance, something like `9.times do |i| it { i.should > 3 } end` would make 9 separate tests for me and have a separate failure trace for each one. what i want is to make `9` dynamic

Comment: well this requires that I know the contents of `@array` beforehand. For my purposes, I was wondering how this could be done if `@array` was populated in the `before(:all)` method, much like my original example. The contents would be set dynamically, depending on what else resulted in that `before(:all)` method.

Comment: I'll try to answer your hypothetical question if I can, but I'm not sure I understand why you can't encode at the top level of `describe` whatever it is you wanted to encode within the `before :all`. It would still be "as dynamic", I would think. If you were using `before :each` it would be a different matter, but with `before :all`, I just don't understand the difference you're seeking.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36689/discussion-between-mango-and-peter-alfvin)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best that I could come up with so far. It's dirty, but if generating tests while iterating an array that isn't pre-defined is what you're after, then you can try to loop a number that you guess will overshoot the filled indexes.

```
require 'rspec'

describe 'a test' do

        before(:all) do
                @array = [1,3,4,6,9,2]
        end 


        16.times do  |i| 
                it 'has a desc' do
                        next if @array[i].nil?
                        @array[i].should > 3   
                end 
        end 


end
```

The caveat here is how you're gonna deal with the tests for indexes past the array's filled index. So far, I've found using `next` to be the cleanest as it just results in another passed test. using `return` or `break` results in proc-closure or jump errors. I also tried wrapping my method in a `begin`,`rescue` block but it seemed it couldn't capture any errors within the `it` block.

Comment: I had thought of this, but I thought you were looking for a way to dynamically generate `it` calls based on data from the `let` and `before` hierarchy of nested `describe` blocks. I still don't know if that's possible.

Comment: i certainly am looking for exactly just that. if you ever think of a way to do so, i'd love to know. This was just the closest solution that i could think of up 'till now.

Comment: I of course appreciate all the help and sticking with me on this on this!^^ You definitely shouldn't have needed to ask all those questions. I should've been clearer on the post. Thanks so much!

Comment: No worries and you're welcome. It was a great question, actually, and I should have upvoted it before now!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you managed to come up with a better answer, but wondering if this would solve the problem for you:

```
RSpec.describe 'a test' do
  array = (1..100).to_a.sample(6)

  array.each do |i|
    it 'has a desc' do
      expect(i).to be > 3
    end
  end
end
```

I think the answer depends on how/why you want the data to vary.